# get URL from onclick handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Given the "`onclick`" string below, how can I extract just the destination URL `("/click/00000/11111/store/afsrc=1")`?

`onclick='javascript:window.open("/click/00000/11111/store/afsrc=1","storepop11111","left=100,top=100,width=1100,height=800,scrollbars,status,resizable,toolbar,menubar,location");’`

I then need to assign that value to a variable to be used elsewhere.

This code is generated dynamically as a whole, and will have a different destination URL depending on the source. So the value will be variable.

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn a little about [string handling in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)...

Comment: so you want just `"/click/00000/11111/store/afsrc=1"` ?

Comment: do you want to overwrite the onclick event, so it doesn't get triggered but you can still extract the URL?

Comment: @JordanDavis, yes just trying to access that string from the onclick, and assign it to a variable

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression.

```
var match = $(element).attr('onclick').match(/window\.open\("([^"]*)"\)/);
var url = match[1];
```

`match[1]` is the part of the attribute value matched by the `([^"]*)` capture group in the regular expression.